# Loading gif before adding cell in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, gif

I'm simulating a chat and I wanted to know how to show a loading gif before message bubble be added in tableview.

Add message function:

```
func addMessage() {
    var message: iMessage
    message = iMessage.initIMessageWithName(self.name, message: self.text, time:self.currentHour(), type "self")
    self.updateTableView(message)
}
```

updateTableView:

```
func updateTableView(msg: AnyObject) {
     self.chatTable!.beginUpdates()
     let row1 NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: currentMessages!.count, inSection: 0)
     currentMessages!.insertObject(msg, atIndex: currentMessages!.count)
     self.chatTable!.insertRowAtIndexPaths(NSArray(objects: row1) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
     self.chatTable!.endUpdates()

     if self.chatTable!.numberOfRowsInSection(0) != 0 {
          let ip: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.chatTable!.numberOfRowsInSection(0)-1, inSection: 0)
          chatTable?.scrollToRowIndexPath(ip, atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
     }
}
```